# how to list all the directories of ftp server of iis using php for download

Tags: php, ftp

I set up my IIS Server in Windows and set a list of folders that should only be downloaded. Now i connected to the server using php too.

```
$username=$_POST["username"];  
$password=$_POST["paswd"];
$host="localhost";
$ftpcon= ftp_connect($host) or die("could not connect");
$login=ftp_login($ftpcon,$username,$password);
```

Now what i want to list is the windows directory. That will help me navigate like the file explorer in windows. Would you mind giving me some help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code to list all your files & directories:

```
<?php
$ftp_server =   'xxx.xx.xx.xx';//Replace with your IP
$conn_id    =    ftp_connect($ftp_server);

# login with username and password
$user   =   'ftp_user_name'; //Replace with your FTP User name
$passwd =   'ftp_password'; //Replace with your FTP Password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $passwd);

# check connection
if (!$conn_id) 
{
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $user";
    exit();
}
else 
{
    $cwd            =   ftp_pwd($conn_id);
    $contentList    =   ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); // This denotes the current path, you can replace this with your actual path

    foreach($contentList as $contentListItem) 
    {
        if (ftp_size($conn_id, $contentListItem) == -1)
        {
            #Its a direcotry
            echo  "Directory : ".$contentListItem."<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            #Its a file
            echo  "File : ".$contentListItem."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning: ftp_login(): End in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainproject\testingconnection.php on line 8

Warning: ftp_pwd(): Please login with USER and PASS. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainproject\testingconnection.php on line 19

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainproject\testingconnection.php on line 22